# VNC connection problem between Windows RealVNC viewer and Ubuntu 18.04 TightVNC server

Tags: server, gnome, vnc, tightvncserver, vncviewer

I want to establish VNC session between RealVNC Viewer in Windows 10 and TightVNC server in Ubuntu 18.04. I want to see from Windows full Ubuntu desktop. I looked at following resources:
[Configuring a VNC Desktop: Upgrading GUI from classic gnome desktop to newest gnome desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097566/configuring-a-vnc-desktop-upgrading-gui-from-classic-gnome-desktop-to-newest-gn)                                                                              [How to configure VNC server to get full Gnome desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898035/how-to-configure-vnc-server-to-get-full-gnome-desktop)        [vnc service for ubuntu 18.04, no background and menus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041260/vnc-service-for-ubuntu-18-04-no-background-and-menus)          [How to make VNC Server work with ubuntu-desktop without xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475023/how-to-make-vnc-server-work-with-ubuntu-desktop-without-xfce?answertab=active#tab-top)
[ubuntu 18.04 VNC Grey screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205687/ubuntu-18-04-vnc-grey-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have used various variants of the xstartup file ~/.vnc/xstartup. However, I cannot find any configuration which is working for me. Below you can find example of the xstartup file.
Ping is working and I can ssh from Windows to Ubuntu. VNC connection is also working. However, after establishing VNC session from Windows machine, I cannot see anything.I get an empty window with grey background. From Linux machine I use Remmina for connection with similar result. I want to see exactly the same desktop as if I am looking at the Ubuntu machine, but I cannot do that.

I would appreciate your help very much.

```
    #!/bin/sh

    export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
    #xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
    unset SESSION_MANAGER
    unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
    #exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

    [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
    [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
    xsetroot -solid grey
    vncconfig -iconic &
    #dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
    #x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
    #x-window-manager &

    gnome-session &
    #sleep4 && gnome-panel &
    #exec gnome-panel-delay
    gnome-panel &
    gnome-settings-daemon &
    metacity &
    #gnome-terminal &
    #nautilus &
    #startxfce4 &
    #startgnome &
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to export your full desktop via VNC, don't use any third-party VNC servers, use "vino" which is integrated with GNOME and exports the full GNOME desktop.
I have used it on 18.04 with success, now use it on 20.04.
There are however some config parameters you have to set for vino-server, look at the answer here: [what is the easy/minimal way to remotely connect a Ubuntu 20.04 system from another Ubuntu 20.04 system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251900/what-is-the-easy-minimal-way-to-remotely-connect-a-ubuntu-20-04-system-from-anot/1251905#1251905)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I followed the instructions and now everything is working fine.