# Remmina: Ubuntu to Ubuntu; RDP, or VNC?

Tags: networking

Using Remmina, to remote from Ubuntu PC to another Ubuntu PC (home network), can I use RDP; or RDP is a Windows Protocol (Remote from Ubuntu to Windows) ?

I am getting "Cannot Connect to the 192.126.1.69 RDP Server" error.

Do I need to configure Remmina to connect from Ubuntu PC to Ubuntu PC via VNC instead?
And if so; do I need to install what 'VNC' and on both PCs, or target PC only ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I did figure it out.

- I can remote from Ubuntu PC to Ubuntu PC by installing Xrdp Server on Traget Ubuntu PC.  I assumed Remmina will install the necessary servers.  It is not the case; after installing Remmina, install RDP Server, and configure ufw Firewall on Target PC.

Instructions are from [How to Install Xrdp Server (Remote Desktop) on Ubuntu 20.04 | Linuxize](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-20-04/).

1. Update first
2. Xrdp is incuded in the default Ubuntu repositories; to install, run:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install xrdp
   ```
3. When installation is complete, the Xrdp service will automatically start. You can verify by typing:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl status xrdp
   ```
4. By default Xrdp uses the `/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` file that is readable only by members of the `ssl-cert` group. Run the following command to add the xrdp user to the group :

   ```
   $ sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
   ```
5. Restart the Xrdp service for changes to take effect:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl restart xrdp
   ```

Firewall:

To allow access to the Xrdp server from a specific IP address or IP range, for example, 192.168.33.0/24, you would run the following command:

```bsh
$ sudo ufw allow # from 192.168.33.0/24 to any port 3389
```

If you want to allow access from anywhere (which is highly discouraged for security reasons), run:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 3389
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also connect via VNC, which is more "natural" for Linux than RDP which is a Windows protocol.

To connect via VNC, you have to install "vino" server on the target PC. I described the procedure here: [what is the easy/minimal way to remotely(over the Internet) connect a Ubuntu 20.04 system from another Ubuntu 20.04 system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251900/what-is-the-easy-minimal-way-to-remotelyover-the-internet-connect-a-ubuntu-20/1251905#1251905)

Comment: > You can also connect via VNC, which is more "natural" for Linux than RDP which is a Windows protocol.> 

Thank you for mentioning so; coming from Windows, thinking like using Windows OS; I will try out VNC, since you say it's more natural for Linux.. a nice way of putting it.. Thank you